# My laravel keeps redirecting to localhost/dashboard whenever I try to type something next to soulfy_repo/public_html/

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

My laravel keeps redirecting to localhost/dashboard whenever I try to type something next to soulfy_repo/public_html

someone mention that I need to change my .htaccess

This is my .htaccess

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
       Options -MultiViews
   </IfModule>

   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

   # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

   # Handle Front Controller...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove **RewriteBase /** form .htaccess OR comment it.